# Proving two distinct primitive roots do not generate $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_n$ in the same order

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

For any suitable $n$ that has primitive roots (i.e. $n$ of the form $2, 4, p^j, 2p^j$, where $p$ is an odd prime), there exist primitive root(s). In the case that $n$ has more than one primitive root, how can I show that they don't generate $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_n$ (the subset of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ whose elements are coprime to $n$) in the same order?

So, for $a$ and $b$ both distinct primitive roots, $a^k \neq b^k$, $k \in [1, \phi(n)-1]$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Isn't $a^k\equiv b^k$ when $k=\phi(n)$?

Comment: Right, I missed that. I was thinking of the case where $n = 9$. $2$ and $5$ are both primitive roots, but they generate $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_9$ in a different order.

Comment: For $2$, we get the set $2,4,8,7,5,1$ while for $5$, we get $5,7,8,4,2,1$.

Comment: $5$ and $11$ are primitive roots mod $18$, but $5^3\equiv11^3\bmod18$

Comment: Is there any way to build a bijective map of $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_n$ to itself, then?

Comment: map one primitive root to another

Answer (score 0):

The following is an argument that works, if I am interpreting "in the same order" correctly. Let $g$ and $h$ be primitive roots modulo $n$ and $i$ be a positive integer less than $\phi(n)$ such that $g^i \equiv h\pmod{n}.$ If the powers of $g$ and $h$ cycle through the coprime residues in the same order, then we have $$gh\equiv g^{i+1}\equiv h^2\pmod{n}.$$ Cancelling $h$ from both sides yields $g\equiv h\pmod{n},$ so $g$ and $h$ are not distinct modulo $n.$